# Возможно не наследовать z-index у родителя?

Tags: css, вёрстка, z-index

Пример в коде. 
Красный квадрат не должен закрывать белую кнопку.

Не очень понимаю как реализовать. Пробовал и absolute ставить на кнопку, толку нет.

```css
.block {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:flex-end;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
 
  
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  bottom: 130px;
  left: 130px;
  z-index:200;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="absolute"></div>
```

Comment: Нет, нельзя, и если вы так делаете, то значит что-то делаете неправильно.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, нельзя.

Z-index работает только в контексте, созданном элементом, имеющим отличный от `auto` `z-index` и отличный от `static` `position` .

Answer (score 0):

Белому блоку можно поставить position: relative; z-index: 201; 
Это конечно не ответ на вопрос, а решение данной задачи)